# Consume React.createContext() implemented in _app.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to access `emailLogin` from my context from another component:

`userContext.js`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import cookie from 'js-cookie';
import {firebase} from './firebase-client';

export const UserContext = React.createContext();
const tokenName = 'firebaseToken';

const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const emailLogin = async (email, password, redirectPath) => {
    await firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('User logged in.');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  const onAuthStateChange = () => {
    return firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
      if (user) {
        const token = await user.getIdToken();
        cookie.set(tokenName, token, { expires: 14 });
      } else {
        cookie.remove(tokenName);
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChange();
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
    
      return <UserContext.Provider value={{ emailLogin }}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>;
    };
    
    export default UserProvider;
```

`_app.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';
import App from 'next/app'
import cookies from 'next-cookies'
import UserProvider from '../lib/userContext'
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import theme from '../theme';

export default function MyApp(props) {
  const { Component, pageProps, user } = props;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector('#jss-server-side');
    if (jssStyles) {
      jssStyles.parentElement.removeChild(jssStyles);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Head>
        <title>My app</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
      </Head>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <UserProvider>
          <Component {...{...pageProps, ...user}} />
        </UserProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
MyApp.getInitialProps = async (userContext) => {
  const { ctx } = userContext;
  let error;
  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(userContext);
  const { firebaseToken } = cookies(ctx);
  if (firebaseToken) {
    try {
      const headers = {
        'Context-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: JSON.stringify({ token: firebaseToken }),
      };
      const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
      const server = dev ? 'http://localhost:3000' : 'https://firebase-app-taupe.vercel.app/';
      const result = await fetch(`${server}/api/validate`, { headers }).then((res) => res.json());
      return { ...result, ...appProps };
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
  return { ...appProps };
};
```

`auth.js`

```
import { useContext } from 'react'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import {Grid, TextField} from '@material-ui/core'
import UserContext from '../lib/userContext'


const auth = () => {
    const { emailLogin } = useContext(UserContext);
  return (
    <Grid container spacing={0} direction="column" alignItems="center" justify="center" style={{ minHeight: '100vh' }}>
      <Grid item>
        <div>
          <TextField value="diegopitt@gmail.com" label="email" /><br /><br />
          <TextField value="12345678" label="password" type="password" /><br /><br />
          <Button variant="contained" color="primary"  onClick={() => login('diegopitt@gmail.com', '12345678')}>Sign In</Button>
        </div>
      </Grid>   
    </Grid> 
  )
}

export default auth
```

How can I access the function emailLogin from auth component?

Comment: Have you tried calling the method from the context you got ?? Like `let ctx = useContext(UserContext); ctx.emailLogin(...)`.

Comment: not sure how to do it. can you post the solution?

Comment: In my auth component I have a login form and I want to access 'emailLogin' to do the validation

Comment: Ok, i'll post an answer try then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're passing an object as your context value, whenever you want to use the rmail field you may do something like:

```
const ctx = useContext(UserContext);
ctx.emailLogin(...)
```

so as to access the `emailLogin` field. Or more simpler : `const { emailLogin } = useContext(UserContext);`

Don't forget to import the `UserContext` first.

Comment: I get `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'emailLogin' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined.` 

I updated the question to show auth.js where I am trying to access `emailLogin`

Comment: Can I see the result of `console.log` or the context object??

Comment: 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: It means that there were an error from the server at some point in the running process. In order to see where, I propose that at each point you catched an error and logged it, you add an error prefix. It will help us understand if it's from your server or from firebase's one. In `userContext.js` it may be `console.log('Login error', err);` and in `_app.js`, `console.log('Request error', err);`

Comment: And in the `auth` component you used `UserProvider` instead of `UserContext` as `useContext` arg

Comment: Ok, I fixed it, now `useContext(UserContext)`  shows undefined